# Ruby Exceptions In A Loop, how to tackle skipped elements?

Tags: ruby, loops

I have a loop, which runs a chain of gsub methods taking a RegExp as an Argument, over 'Macro' text templates which I feed into the loop. Some have all of the desired RegExp matches, others have only one or two. The next element in the loop is being skipped as a result. How do I retry the ensure the loop continues, only skipping the .match that is unfulfilled?

Macro Objects:

```
 [{"url"=>"macros/360081752739.json",
  "id"=>360081752739,
  "actions"=>[{"field"=>"comment_value_html", "value"=>" DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00 DE89370400440532013000 test@gmail.com "}],
  "restriction"=>nil},
 {"url"=>"macros/360081755559.json",
  "id"=>360081755559,
  "actions"=>[{"field"=>"comment_value_html", "value"=>"test@gmail.com "}],
  "restriction"=>nil}]
```

Loop:

```
 PARTS = [
{ re: /\bDE(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]\s?){20}\b/, name: 'IBAN' },
{ re: /\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b/, name: 'E-Mail' },
{ re: /\b(0|0049\s?|\+49\s?|\(\+49\)\s?){1}([1-9]{2,4})([ \-\
/]?[0-9]{1,10})+\b/, name: 'Phone Number' }].freeze

PARTS.each do |x|
  list = macros.select { |m| m['actions'].any? { |w| x[:re].match?(w['value']) } }.map { |m| m['id'] }
  puts "Macro ID with #{x[:name]} #{list}"

  list.each do |i|
    @id = i
    data_macro = macros.select { |m| m['actions'].any? { |w| x[:re].match?(w['value']) } }.to_s.gsub(/\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b/, '{{email}}').gsub(/\bDE(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]\s?){20}\b/, '{{IBAN}}').gsub(/\b(0|0049\s?|\+49\s?|\(\+49\)\s?){1}([1-9]{2,4})([ \-\/]?[0-9]{1,10})+\b/, '{{phone_number}}')
    hash = eval(data_macro)
    data_hash = hash.to_json
    @final_data = JSON.parse(data_hash)
  end
end
```

Expected Output:

```
 [{"url"=>"macros/360081752739.json",
  "id"=>360081752739,
  "actions"=>[{"field"=>"comment_value_html", "value"=>" {{IBAN}} {{IBAN}} {{email}} "}],
  "restriction"=>nil},
 {"url"=>"macros/360081755559.json",
  "id"=>360081755559,
  "actions"=>[{"field"=>"comment_value_html", "value"=>"{{email}} "}],
  "restriction"=>nil}]
```

Actual Output:

```
 [{"url"=>"macros/360081752739.json",
  "id"=>360081752739,
  "actions"=>[{"field"=>"comment_value_html", "value"=>" {{IBAN}} {{IBAN}} {{email}} "}],
  "restriction"=>nil},
 {"url"=>"macros/360081755559.json",
  "id"=>360081755559,
  "actions"=>[{"field"=>"comment_value_html", "value"=>"test@gmail.com "}],
  "restriction"=>nil}]
```

Comment: Why is that `rescue` there? Are you getting any actual exceptions/errors?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, I'm not receiving an error, the script runs to completion. I thought it would also help in continuing the loop/method chain, but clearly not.

Comment: yeah, `rescue`/`retry` have very specific purpose. It's not a kind of magic dust you sprinkle on top of code to help it work better. That said, this is the second iteration of your question that I've seen and I still have no idea what is the problem you're experiencing. You have expected/actual outputs in the post, that's very good. But what would be even better is an actual [mcve] (something I can run myself, including everything needed to reproduce the problem). At a glance, what you have is _almost_ that. But at least one name is undefined: `macros`.

Comment: @Sergio Thanks for the info, Is the update sufficient? Macro is an Array of Objects returned from an API.

Comment: Better, but it really should be in the main script, `macros = [...`. Again, it's in your best interests to make it as effortless for us to see the problem as possible. I have tried to run your code, but it appears that declaration of `PARTS` is not syntactically complete. Or, at least, not IRB-friendly. When I paste it in IRB, it starts expecting more input to complete the expresssion.

Comment: Same if I try to run it as a file.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Interesting, unfortunately I'm not sure how to proceed in regards to reformatting this question, as it 'works'/doesn't throw errors in my console. The puts statement is also accurate when I run the script.

Comment: Don't know what you're running in your console, but it's not what you have in this question, I'm quite sure. https://pastebin.com/8Y6AkAf5

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes that's would be the only thing that makes sense to explain our differing result, but I've gone line by line with what I 'believe' is the only relevant code, however here is the full unedited script (bar the addition of macros defined inscript'. https://pastebin.com/Pn7C5A58

Comment: Ah, it's already different. What you have here is weirdly split over several lines. When I fix that and add a `require 'json'` on top of the file, it starts giving me _some_ output.

Comment: See how not complete or reproducible it was? It feels like work at this point, and I'd rather be doing my actual work. When I get some downtime, I'll try to look at this again.

Comment: Ah, it's still not complete. Neither this post nor your unedited pastebin contain any puts statements that could produce output like `Macro2: "text-value": "test@gmail.com"`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I see, I'll keep this question as a template for how not to ask Q's in the future. I can see I remove far too much relevant code in an effort to make it minimal. I've updated the expected output too.